# 3tire Web application publish error?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

I create one website in 3 tire architecture and its working local but when I publish and upload in .net server  in live it gives error

**Error**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'urprofessional.Clients.index'.

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="urprofessional.Clients.index" %>
```

Comment: Have you checked your paranthesis?

Answer (score 0):

**Try it:-**

change `CodeBehind="OutReport.aspx.cs"` to `CodeFile="OutReport.aspx.cs"`

or

for me, the fix was to change the output path in the build tab.

I changed the output path to bin\ and the error went away.

refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7394836/2798643)

Refer this link: [Could not load type](http://blog.techdreams.org/2008/04/could-not-load-type-aspnet-20-error-and.html)

or

refer this link [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18018014/2798643) here was same problem.

or

refer [could not load type](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/169602/Parser-Error-Message-Could-not-load-type)

or

[Project Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698%28VS.100%29.aspx)

I hope it may will help you.

Comment: I upload only aspx and dll i dont have aspx.cs file in server it convert in dll     arser Error Message: The file '/urprofessional/Clients/index.aspx.cs' does not exist.

Source Error:


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="urprofessional.Clients.index" %>

Comment: Have you set output path='\bin'?refer here to understand about problem http://blog.techdreams.org/2008/04/could-not-load-type-aspnet-20-error-and.html

Comment: GovindaRajbhar any other help

Comment: @LingrajGowda sorry friend I could not get solution.if i will get then i will help you.